# Include php not working linux apache2

Tags: php, linux, apache2, debian

Good day. Maybe, it's a duplicate, but I didn't found an answer for me. I have developed a PHP site on local server (Apache2.4, Windows) and all were working. Including files isn't working on Debian VPS server with apache2. What can cause this problem?

```
<? include '/include/libs.php';?>
```

Comment: Have you enable short opening tags? otherwise use this: `<?php include '/include/libs.php';?>`

Comment: i will  bet, there is no dir **include** in root dir ;) check your include paths or the better way, use absolute paths for include / require

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Also check file permissions.

Comment: I set all to 777 - now 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three reasons I'm guessing
First:
You may not have privileges/permissions to access the file your trying to include.
   Usually, this is the very error involved with failed include statements.
   Try running this code:
  `<?php
  var_dump(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/include/libs.php')), -4));
 ?>`

  If the last three digits of output are less than 7, 5 and 5 respectively then you're caught up in a file permission problem.
You can resolve this error by changing the including file(s) permissions in bash
 `sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/include/libs.php`
Use `sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/html/include/libs.php` instead, if, your apache version is above 2.4
Note that you need to use the `-R` flag for chmod so that all your enclosing folders are also chmodded.

Second:
You are not running php as the default apache2 user-group OR your includee file belongs to root.
This, like the previous reason is also file permission exception.
run

 `sudo chown "www-data" /var/www/include/libs.php`
OR
 `sudo chgrp "www-data" /var/www/include/libs.php`
followed by `sudo service apache2 restart` in bash.
Third:
You may have screwed your apache2/PHP installation/configuration settings.
Hit `sudo apt-get purge php5` and the `sudo apt-get install php5` in bash.
Keep in mind that his WILL burn all your custom `php.ini` settings and you may need to start configuring right from the beginning. [ I learned this the hard way :D ].


Hope this helps ...

UPDATE:
After i read that there is no error shown,
it occurred to me you have the default php5 config ...
open `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
Change the line `display_errors = Off` to `display_errors = On`
This was the problem I had when I installed php from scratch ...

Comment: Thanks very much! Errors are visible now. I will solve

Comment: I have a question... Include didn't work because my site is in /var/www, but it finds in root directory. How I can set that PHP finds file path relatively to /var/www?

Comment: The very problem is the fact that you are adding a '/' (slash) in front of '/include/libs.php'. LOSE the slash in the front and your good to go :) [ Just use 'include/libs.php' ]